# Command line messages disappear in a flash

Tags: gvim, message

A while back I started using `guioptions +=k` to (from `help guioptions`):

> Keep the GUI window size when adding/removing a scrollbar, or
>         toolbar, tabline, etc.  Instead, the behavior is similar to         when
>   the window is maximized and will adjust 'lines' and       'columns' to fit
>   to the window.  Without the 'k' flag Vim will         try to keep 'lines'
>   and 'columns' the same when adding and        removing GUI components.

However, now I can't seem to turn it off, and it may (or may not) be responsible for a problem: If I use a command such as `:pwd` the response immediately disappears as the bottom of the window does a little spasm and replaces the command output with the line that ends, e.g., "1,0-1  All" (dunno what that is called).

The same goes for things such as error messages -- all I see is a red flash and there is no time to read them.  Fortunately, `:messages` works, so I can find out what they were.

I notice `help error` mentions there is a limit to how long some messages will appear, but no means to set that.  I don't have this problem in non-GUI vim, in which case the output remains visible until I access the command line again.

Answer (score 2):

So the issue wasn't `guioptions`, it was `guiheadroom`; I finally noticed this because while I keep my config files synced, the stub `~/.vimrc` which sources them isn't, to accomodate local settings. One of which, on another system where I do not have the problem, is:

```
set guiheadroom=0
```

I added this here, restarted gvim and problem solved.  From `:help guiheadroom`:

> **'guiheadroom' 'ghr'**   number  (default 50)            global
>
> *{not in Vi} {only for GTK and X11 GUI}*
>
> The number of pixels subtracted from the screen
>   height when fitting   the GUI window on the screen.  Set this before
>   the GUI is started,   e.g., in your `gvimrc` file.  When zero, the
>   whole screen height will  be used by the window.  When positive, the
>   specified number of pixel     lines will be left for window decorations
>   and other items on the    screen.  Set it to a negative value to allow
>   windows taller than the   screen.

Note that this didn't actually change the base appearance; the window still fills the screen exactly like before and the titlebar and decorations are evident.  However, messages at the bottom no longer disappear in a blur.